# Changing the view from isolated EventHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, eventhandler

So I have a class (MeetingHandler) where I have multiple private classes inside - one for each type of "View" I want to create based on the state of the parent class (upcoming meeting, happening meeting, happened meeting). 
Inside each of these classes I just return a HtmlGenericControl containing all the elements I need.

The problem I'm having is that I can't find out how to update the view in the eventhandler of the button. What I want to do is remove the div containing the "meeting comment" that has been removed.

Maybe this is just the wrong approach all together, I'd love to get some input

Comment: Have you tried debugging in Visual Studio? See which line is flagging the exception?

Comment: PS. Accidentally posted with wrong headline, sorry, I'm not having problems with a null reference.

Comment: Why are you trying to remove DOM elements like div from C#? You can do it on the client side using Javascript.

Comment: That's a fair point, I guess. I'm still learning and I've never done this before, so that's probably why. Could you please elaborate on how to implement that for this scenario? :)

Comment: Please post your HTML code of the view too, without that I can't make assumptions.

Comment: I think I've added what you asked for now.